Why does $ \arccos(\cos \phi \cdot \cos x) \approx (\phi-\frac{\pi}{2})\cos\ x+\frac{\pi}{2}$?
The equation $$y = \arccos(\cos \phi \cdot \cos x)$$ is this solution to this problem in solid geometry.  When graphing it, I noticed that is visually almost identical to the simpler equation $$y = (\phi-\frac{\pi}{2})\cos\ x+\frac{\pi}{2}$$ for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$.


Why is that? Is there a way to prove that one approximates the other, or to bound the error? Is there any intuition behind this?

Presumably, for fixed $\phi.$ The right side is unbounded for arbitrary $\phi.$

@ThomasAndrews Yes, for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$.

The approximation seems to be good for $\phi\in[0,\pi]$

Consider $w = \arcsin( \sin \alpha \cdot z)$, where $|z|\le 1$, then using the approximations $\sin x \approx x$ and $\arcsin x \approx x$ for small $x$, you get $w \approx \alpha \cdot z$. That’s essentially what’s happening here with $w = \pi/2 - y$, $\alpha = \pi/2-\phi$, and $z= \cos x$.

The original function is periodic, with a period of $2\pi$, varying around $\arccos(0)=\pi/2$, smooth, with maxima and minima where $\sin x=0$.

@Pranay Care to expand your comment into a full answer? Many people clearly like it, but it's hard to unpack as a comment.  In particular, how are the small angle approximations applicable, when the values aren't necessarily small?

FWIW, if you allow a maximum error of $0.01$, then $\sin x \approx x$ is valid for $|x| \le 0.392$, $\cos x \approx 1$ is valid for $|x| \le 0.141$, and $\cos x \approx 1 - x^2/2$ is valid for $|x| \le 0.702$.

@SRobertJames Just added an answer expanding on my comment.

The trigonometry(or trigonometry-like) functions can be similar iff its period is same, its amplitude is same, and the starting point is same.

Let us define $w=\pi/2-y$, $\alpha = \pi/2 - \phi$ and $z=\pi/2 - x$. Then, the given equation is
$$
w = \arcsin(\sin \alpha \sin z).
$$
We want to compare this with $\alpha \sin z$. More precisely, we want to upper bound the error function,
$$
f(\alpha,z) := \alpha \sin z - \arcsin(\sin \alpha \sin z),
$$
where $\alpha\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $z\in [0,\pi/2]$ (by various symmetries, it is enough to analyze in this domain). Note that $f(0,z) = 0$, i.e., the error is zero when $\alpha = 0$, so I restrict to $\alpha>0$ below.
In the following, I use prime ($'$) to denote derivative with respect to $z$ and dot ($\dot{}$) to denote derivative with respect to $\alpha$.

First, let's show that $f(\alpha,z)$ is always nonnegative in this domain. Since $f(\alpha,0) = f(\alpha,\pi/2) = 0$, it is enough to show that $f(\alpha,z)$ has only one local maximum in the interval $z\in(0,\pi/2)$. Equivalently, we need to show that $f'(\alpha,z)$ has only one zero in this interval. Let us look at the zeros of $f'$:
$$
f'(\alpha,z) = \left(\alpha - \frac{\sin \alpha}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2 z}}\right) \cos z = 0.
$$
Since $\cos z \ne 0$ for $z\in(0,\pi/2)$, we have
$$
g(\alpha,z) := \alpha - \frac{\sin \alpha}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2 z}}=0.
$$
Since $g(\alpha,0) = \alpha - \sin \alpha > 0$, $g(\alpha,\pi/2) = \alpha - \tan \alpha < 0$, and
$$
g'(\alpha,z) = - \frac{\sin^3 \alpha \sin z \cos z}{(1-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2 z)^{3/2}} \le 0,
$$
we conclude that $g(\alpha,z)$ has only one zero in $z\in(0,\pi/2)$. Therefore, $f(\alpha,z)$ is always nonnegative.

Let us bound the error now. For each $\alpha$, the maximum occurs at $z_\alpha$ given by
$$
g(\alpha,z_\alpha) = 0 \implies \sin z_\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 - \sin^2\alpha}}{\alpha \sin\alpha}.
$$
The quantity on the RHS is at least $0$ trivially, and at most $1$ because
$$
\alpha<\tan \alpha \implies \alpha^2 \cos^2\alpha - \sin^2 \alpha <0 \implies \alpha^2 -\sin^2 \alpha < \alpha^2 \sin^2\alpha.
$$
Therefore, for each $\alpha$, the maximum error is
$$
h(\alpha) := f(\alpha,z_\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 - \sin^2\alpha}}{\sin\alpha} - \arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 - \sin^2\alpha}}{\alpha}\right).
$$
Now, note that, for any fixed $z \in [0,\pi/2]$, we have
$$
\dot f(\alpha,z) = \sin z\left( 1 - \frac{\cos \alpha}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2 z}} \right) = \sin z \left( 1- \sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2 \alpha}{1-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2 z}} \right) \ge 0.
$$
Therefore, for any fixed $z$, $f(\alpha,z)$ is an increasing function of $\alpha$. This means $h(\alpha)$ is also increasing with $\alpha$. So, the maximum possible error is
$$
h(\pi/2) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}4 - 1} - \arcsin\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac4{\pi^2}}\right) \approx 0.33.
$$

Personally, I don't think this is a small error. Indeed,
$$
f(\pi/2,z) = \frac{\pi}{2} \sin z - z,
$$
and I don't think $2z/\pi$ and $\sin z$ are particularly close. But for small $\alpha$, expanding around $\alpha=0$ gives
$$
h(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha^3}{9\sqrt3} + O(\alpha^5).
$$
In fact, one can check numerically that
$$
0 \le h(\alpha) - \frac{\alpha^3}{9\sqrt3} \lesssim 0.082.
$$
So it seems like $\frac{\alpha^3}{9\sqrt3}$ is a good approximation of the maximum error for any $\alpha$, and for small $\alpha$, it is indeed small.

You could go further if you expand around $\phi=\frac \pi 2$
$$\arccos(\cos (\phi) \, \cos (x))=\color{red}{\left(\phi -\frac{\pi }{2}\right) \cos(x)+\frac{\pi }{2}}-$$
$$\sin^2(x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)\, \left(\phi -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2n+1}$$ the first $P_n(x)$ being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(x) \\
 1 & \frac{\cos (x)}{6} \\
 2 & \frac{23 \cos (x)+9 \cos (3 x)}{480}  \\
 3 & \frac{1186 \cos (x)+765 \cos (3 x)+225 \cos (5 x)}{80640} \\
 4 & \frac{110123 \cos (x)+87129 \cos (3 x)+45675 \cos (5 x)+11025 \cos (7 x)}{23224320} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Computing, for $\phi=\frac \pi 4$, the infinite norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\arccos(\cos (\phi) \, \cos (x))-\text{approximation}_n \Big)^2 \,dx$$ as well as the maximum absolute error $\Delta_n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \Phi_n & \Delta_n\\
 0 & 2.98629\times 10^{-3} & 3.31253\times 10^{-2} \\
 1 & 2.83475\times 10^{-5} & 3.81911\times 10^{-3} \\
 2 & 4.53754\times 10^{-7} & 5.56005\times 10^{-4} \\
 3 & 1.01325\times 10^{-8} & 9.11414\times 10^{-5} \\
 4 & 2.79939\times 10^{-10} & 1.60988\times 10^{-5} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
